# Spark 2.3, Attribute(s) with the same name appear in the operation

Tags: sql, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Let's say I have two tables with same columns and I suspect there might be some rows that are different between the two tables. So I execute the following query to check that:

```
SELECT
reconnectTimeStamp,
prevreconnectMilliSecondTimeStampS,
prev_reconnect_interfaceMacS,
reconnect_homeS
FROM t_reconnect_disconnect_prior_V1

EXCEPT

SELECT
reconnectTimeStamp,
prevreconnectMilliSecondTimeStampS,
prev_reconnect_interfaceMacS,
reconnect_homeS
FROM t_reconnect_disconnect_prior_V2
```

This returns the following error:

> Attribute(s) with the same name appear in the operation: prevreconnectMilliSecondTimeStampS,prev_reconnect_interfaceMacS. Please check if the right attribute(s) are used

If I change my query to this, it works without an error:

```sql
SELECT
reconnectTimeStamp,
prevreconnectMilliSecondTimeStampS as c1,
prev_reconnect_interfaceMacS as c2,
reconnect_homeS
FROM t_reconnect_disconnect_prior_V1

EXCEPT

SELECT
reconnectTimeStamp,
prevreconnectMilliSecondTimeStampS as c1,
prev_reconnect_interfaceMacS as c2,
reconnect_homeS
FROM t_reconnect_disconnect_prior_V2
```

Can you come up with any explanation for that to happen? What is different with only these 2 column names?

P.S. Those are the only columns that are created ambiguosly in another temp view to end up in these views.

```
select
lag(reconnect_milliSecondTimeStampS, 1, "1898868600000") OVER (PARTITION BY  
                                            reconnect_homeS, reconnect_stationMacS ORDER BY reconnect_milliSecondTimeStampS ASC) 
                                                                                    as prevreconnectMilliSecondTimeStampS,
lag(reconnect_interfaceMacS, 1, "1898868600000") OVER (PARTITION BY 
                                            reconnect_homeS, reconnect_stationMacS ORDER BY reconnect_milliSecondTimeStampS ASC) 
                                                                                    as prev_reconnect_interfaceMacS

FROM some_table
```

Comment: Are these tables the temporary tables created from some dataframes by using createOrReplaceTempView? Not pretty sure what is causing this but I have a feeling this issue could be caused due to ambiguous columns created when you reuse the same dataframe.

Comment: Exactly, they are created via createOrReplaceTempView. Actually, they are the only columns that are not taken directly from another table but as a result of the lag function applied which renamed afterwards.

Comment: Okay in that case the problem is something similar to what is reported here .https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-10925 . I had encountered similar issue wherein I did a bunch of transformations using multiple base DFs ,created a final DF which had to be used in subsequent transformations using the base DFs as reference. The issue was solved by creating a copy of the dataframe which was causing the ambiguity. In your case if you rename the attributes at the time of creation of t_reconnect_disconnect_prior_V1 and t_reconnect_disconnect_prior_V2 then it should solve the problem